# Get the number of character classes from an argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program takes a single string as a command line argument. It should print out the number of character classes contained in that string, e.g. for `aBN1`.

```
import sys

a = sys.argv[1]
if a.upper():  
    a = 1
elif a.lower():
    a = a + 1
elif a.digit():
    a = a + 1
else:
    a = a + 1
```

I use a for loop to include four character classes: digits, lower case characters, upper case characters and special characters, i.e. everything else.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Im trying to take an argument and see how many character clsses it contains eg aBN1 contains 3 small character upper character and a integer.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? SO is not a "solve my homework" service.

Comment: updated do I need use find module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [zondo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241370/get-number-character-classes-from-an-argument/35242044#35242044), this is what I came up with:

```
import sys

s = sys.argv[1]
methods = {str.isdigit: 'd', str.isupper: 'u', str.islower: 'l', (lambda c: (not str.isdigit(c) and not str.isupper(c) and not str.islower(c))):'s'}
result = set()
for c in s:
    for m in methods:
        if m(c):
            result.add(methods[m])
print(len(result))
```

Comment: Here you go: [lambda-expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)

Comment: @DeclanLunney if you find an answer good for you please "Accept" it by clicking on the check-mark next to it

Answer (score 2):

Another approach but using a **set comprehension** + **next**

```
test_str = 'aBN1*'
methods = {str.isdigit: 'd', str.isupper: 'u', str.islower: 'l'}
result = {
    next((methods[m] for m in methods if m(c)),'s')
    for c in test_str
}
```

output:

```
set(['s', 'u', 'l', 'd'])
```

A second one, but this time using **collections.Counter** + **next**:

```
from collections import Counter
test_str = 'aBN1*'
methods = {str.isdigit: 'd', str.isupper: 'u', str.islower: 'l'}
result = Counter(
    next((methods[m] for m in methods if m(c)), 's')
    for c in test_str
)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'u': 2, 's': 1, 'l': 1, 'd': 1})
```

As you can see, there are many ways of doing it, the last one give you how many characters in each character class.

Another way, but this time leveraging the **strings** module of the stdlib:

```
from string import digits
from string import punctuation
from string import ascii_lowercase
from string import ascii_uppercase

c_classes = {digits: 'd', punctuation: 's', ascii_lowercase: 'l', ascii_uppercase: 'u'}
{c_classes[cclass] for cclass in c_classes for c in test_str if c in cclass}
```

output:

```
set(['s', 'u', 'd', 'l'])
```

You can of course use the Counter here as well.
However I believe that the last technique using the string helpers might be heavier in terms of loops because I had to check if the character is in each predefined list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: %s string" % sys.argv[0], file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

methods = {str.isdigit: 0, str.isupper: 0, str.islower: 0}
special = 0
for character in sys.argv[1]:
    old_values = methods.values()
    is_special = 1
    for method in methods:
        if method(character):
            methods[method] = 1
            is_special = 0
    if is_special:
        special = 1

print(sum(methods.values() + [special]))
```

Comment: Is there A more concise way you could do this?

Comment: I haven't gotten anything yet, but I'll work on it.  I think I might be able to do it in only about 6 lines.

Comment: I guess I was a little hasty with that `6 lines` bit, but this is a little more concise.